# Finding Invariant Factors of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the invariant factors of the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

From what I gather, I have to use elementary row operations on $xI - A$ until I obtain a diagonal matrix, and the nonzero diagonal entries form the invariant factors of $A$. Well, I tried this multiple times and these are some of the results of what I got:

$$\begin{pmatrix} (1-x)(x^2-2x) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -x^2 + 2x & 0 \\ 0 & 2x + 1 & 2-x \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} (x-1)^3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & (x-1)^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & (x-2)(x-1)^3 \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} (x-1)^3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & (x-1)^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & (x-2)(x-1)^3 \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

But none of these seem right. Either the degree of the polynomials is too high or the right divisibility relation does not hold. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am very awful at calculating, but I didn't think I was that awful.

Perhaps there is an easier way. I know that the largest invariant factor is the minimal polynomial, and the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial. A quick calculation (which wolframalpha did for me, because I don't trust myself) reveals that $p_{A}(x) = -x(x-2)^2$ is the minimal polynomial. Clearly $x$ and $x-2$ are not the minimal polynomials of $A$, so $m_A(x) = (x-2)^2$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. At this point, can I conclude what the invariant factors of $A$ are? I know they have to divide $m_A$.

Comment: You have a matrix with coefficients in $\bf Z$. What is an indeterminate doing here?

Comment: @Bernard I am supposed to regard the matrix as living in $M_3(\Bbb{Q})$. I don't know what you mean by indeterminate.

Comment: As in $K[X]$ (polynomial ring in one indeterminate over a field $K$)

Comment: But perhaps, you're looking for the *similarity invariants*?

Comment: @Bernard Okay. I still don't quite understand what you're hinting at. Invariant factors, minimal polynomials, and characteristic polynomials are--well--polynomials; i.e., elements of $k[x]$. So it's natural that the indeterminate shows up.

Comment: @Bernard I am looking for invariant factors because I am trying to compute the rational canonical form of $A$.

Comment: Not exactly: as a matrix in $\mathcal  M_3(\mathbf Z)$, it also has invariant factors, as all matrices with coefficients in a P.I.D. But these invariant factors are integers.

Comment: @Bernard Okay, but what are the invariant factors if we consider $A$ as living in $M_3(\Bbb{Q})$?

Comment: There's none. Probably, the vector space $\mathbf Q^3$ is endowed with a  $\mathbf Q[X]$-module structure through the matrix.

Comment: @Bernard OP is looking for the invariant factors of $xI - A$ as an element of $M_3(\Bbb Q[x])$.

Comment: @Bernard huh!? Then how do I calculate the rational canonical form of $A$. Surely my professor didn't make a mistake in this problem.

Comment: @Bernard or equivalently we are thinking of $\Bbb Q^3$ as a $\Bbb Q[x]$ module with the action of $x$ given by $A$. Cf. the wiki on [Frobenius canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#General_case_and_theory)

Comment: If @BenGrossmann's comment is correct, you should look at [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

Comment: @BenGrossmann So, is there a way of fixing my calculations, or is the idea about finding the minimal polynomial better? I also have to calculate the Jordan, so I already need the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @user I'm very confused about *"...reveals that $p_{A}(x) = -x(x-2)^2$ is the minimal polynomial. Clearly $x$ and $x-2$ are not the minimal polynomials of $A$, so $m_A(x) = (x-2)^2$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$."* How did you get from "the minimal polynomial is $-x(x-2)^2$" to "the minimal polynomial is $(x-2)^2$? We can't have two distinct minimal polynomials

Comment: @BenGrossmann Whoops, I meant to say that $p_A(x) = -x(x-2)^2$ is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: You should be ending up with the smith form 
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&(x-2)(x-1)^2}
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann You get that from row reducing $xI-A$? So, my idea about finding minimal polynomial and then using it to find the other invariant factors won't work?

Comment: @user Sorry, that should be
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&x(x-2)^2}
$$
But yes, that is what you should get if you reduce $xI - A$. Alternatively, the minimal polynomial is equal to the largest invariant factor, and the characteristic polynomial is the product of all invariant factors. Once you correctly come to the conclusion that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x(x-2)^2$, you can deduce that it has its minimal polynomial as its invariant factor

Comment: @user So to be clear, your conclusion that $(x-2)^2$ is the minimal polynomial is wrong

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick way to find the invariant factors.

First, compute the characteristic polynomial $p(x) = \det(xI - A) = x(x-2)^2$. Each degree $1$ factor of the characteristic polynomial must be a factor of the minimal polynomial, so the minimal polynomial is either $x(x-2)$ or $x(x-2)^2$.

One way to show that the minimal polynomial is not $x(x-2)$ is to compute $A(A-2I)$ and verify that you do not end up with the zero matrix.

Alternatively, it suffices to find the rank of $A - 2I$. Note that if $A$ has minimal polynomial $x(x-2)$ (i.e. the minimal polynomial is a product of distinct degree one factors), then $A$ must be diagonalizable. This would mean that we have $\dim\ker(A - 0I) + \dim \ker(A - 2 I ) = 3$. We must have $\dim \ker A = 1$ since $0$ is an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $1$. We find that $\dim \ker (A - 2 I) = 1$ (or correspondingly that $A - 2 I$ has rank $2$), which means that the sum of the dimensions of the kernels is *not* equal to $3$, which means that $A$ is not diagonalizable, which means that the minimal polynomial must be $x(x-2)^2$.

Since the characteristic and minimal polynomials are equal, deduce that $x(x-2)^2$ is the only invariant factor of $A$.